# Giant slayer, witch hunter: why the singular form?

Tags: collocation

It is clear that the meaning of the collocations is:
slayer of giants
hunter of witches

But, why do they stay in singular when they are in a juxtaposition?
What is their grammatical funticion? Which case is that?

Comment: Why isn't it *mice trap, teethbrush* or *eggs carton*?

Comment: English generally—not always—uses singular nouns to modify other nouns. (There's no pattern to the exceptions, except often the plural is used when the singular noun would cause confusion.) English hasn't had noun cases for centuries; maybe this is a remnant of some noun case in Old English; maybe not. That would be a good question, but it's not the one you're asking, so we closed it as a duplicate.